# Ajax call does not receive any return data

Tags: angularjs, ajax

I would like to ask why my second ajax call does not get any data..

Here is my Ajax code:

```
$scope.setArticleList = function(page){
    if(page == $scope.paging.page){
        $http({
            method : 'POST',
            url : API_URL + "article/get/mainArticleView/" + page + "/" + $scope.paging.size,
            data : $.param($scope.active_filter),
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
        }).success(function(response_article){
            if (page == $scope.paging.page) {
                $scope.article_list = response_article.data_article;
                $scope.paging.total = response_article.total_page;
            }
        });
    }
    $http({
        method : 'GET',
        url : API_URL + "article/get/mainCategoryView"
    }).success(function(response_category){
        $scope.category_list = response_category.data_category;
        console.log(response_category);
    });
};
```

The Ajax call for `article_list` gets the `response.data`, but no data from category_list..

I have checked that the query is not empty.

Comment: Have you confirmed that the code block is actually running, e.g. placed a debugger or console.log in the .error handler or something?

Comment: Open up Chrome's network tools, and check if the API call is actually being made, and if there are any errors.